# Como realizar un SETTER en java con tipos ENUMERADOS por teclado y sin teclado

Tags: java

Buenas, no se como poder trabajar con SET y enum, me da el error de:
 incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Tipo
        this.tipo=tipo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Maverkk, te recominendo agregar el código y no usar imagen en este caso, realiza el [tour] y revisa por favor [ask], saludos

Answer (score 1):

Los tipos enumerados no son tipo `String`, son tipo `enum`. Lo que debes pasar por parámetro es un tipo `enum`.

```
public void setTipo(Tipo tipo){
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

Y entonces...

> - **Pregunta:** ¿Cómo hago para pedir un dato`enum` por consola y pasárselo al objeto coche en cuestión?
> - **Respuesta:** Simplemente, no puedes.

Lo que debes hacer es un método intermediario que solicite el tipo enum o a través de una selección numérica de opciones:

> Tipo de combustible:
>
> 1. Para Diésel.
> 2. Para Gasolina.
> 3. Para eléctrico.
>
> Introduce una opción:

O también una cadena de caracteres:

> Introduce el tipo de combustible:

Lo importante es que después de la introducción de datos, evalúes el dato introducido y en caso de ser correcto, le pase el tipo `enum` adecuado al método setter.